# How to rotate layout in android?

Tags: android

How should i rotate i.e., how to apply animation to layout when i passing from one activity to another activity in android?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code snippet: `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

Comment: Not in landscape or portrait while going from A->B activity layout should rotate 90 degrees, while comng back from B->A it shold move 180 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of research to do my friend!

Firstly your question is very vague, secondly, it doesn't make much sense- why would you be dealing with rotation when "passing from one activity to another"?

When an activity is in view and you rotate the device, this is called a configuration change (i.e the screen dimensions have now changed). By default, android deals with this by destroying your activity and re-creating it. If you want a different layout for your landscape and portrait views then android has a very elegant way to implement this. You can create a "layout-land" folder in your res folder and place a landscape version of your layout xml file in there (with the same name as your portrait version, eg main.xml). Android will then dynamically load the appropriate layout file depending on the current configuration in the onCreate method of your activity.

See http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/7/ for a basic tutorial on this although i'm sure there are better ones out there.

Of course, you might not want a different layout and if this is the case you can disable this process of destroying and recreating the activity and android will just reflow your layout instead -

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

Comment: Ok, so you want the new activity to be landscape but when you go back, you want the old activity to be portrait. If you set android:screenOrientation="portrait" in the manifest for the first activity and android:screenOrientation="landscape" for the second activity, this should achieve what you are looking for. Just beware that with this technique both of those activities will have locked orientations.

Comment: No not rotaion in landscape or portrait i would like to apply animation while going from one activity to another activity(Viceversa).

Comment: So you want to start the new activity in landscape but you want it to actually animate as it comes in? Normally when an activity launches I believe it's animation is inherited form the system but you can use overridePendingTransition to specify a custom animation. Create an anim folder in your res and create an xml file with your custom animation in then use overridePendingTransition to specifiy this new anim for the acitivty switch transition

Answer (score 0):

there two kind of orientation's landScape and portrait . so 90 degree or 189 degree does not make any sense . like if you want to reverse screen , it not possible .

so First Read orientation , then swap it if needed .